# How to convert char* to std::string if it have to contain cyrillic characters?

Tags: c++, encoding

I'm using a C library to analyze MS Excel files. The reading function returns char* string which I have to convert into std::string. The problem is my files contain cyrillic symbols so I get strings like "РЎРґРµР»РєР°" (instead of "Сделка")

I've tried using std::wstring but this ended up corrupting characters even more. I also tried to use Notepad++ to restore characters and it worked: pasting output string into new document and pressing "Encode in UTF8" makes the correct word appear, but none of my tries to make this in code were succesfull. So it seems like chsr* string is ANSI string and the std::string I want is UTF8 string, but none of the algorythms I found worked.

Fragment of my code

```cpp
char* value;
while ((value = xlsxioread_sheet_next_cell(sheet)) != NULL)
{
    std::string str(value);
    std::cout << str << " ";
}
```

And inside main() I have

```cpp
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

**The goal is to make a std::string containing cyrillic characters out of char* string.**

Note:

```cpp
// works fine
std::string str = "Абвгдеж"; // str contains Абвгдеж
std::cout << str; // outputs Абвгдеж
```

Comment: It looks like you have properly read the string as UTF-8. Is your problem how to make the characters to show correctly in the console? If so, [edit] your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: Is'nt std::string redundant? If you are using it only in the loop you could just cout <<  value << " ". @Ville-Valtteri states you read proper UTF-8, that's true. You should go UTF-8 all the way in your code:

* Try SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)
* Remember char* and std::string can hold utf8 without "strange" conversions.
* Read http://utf8everywhere.org and http://utf8everywhere.org/#windows

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri I have to work with it further, so i need a std::string with cyrillic characters inside. I need the way to make a std::string containing "Сделка" out of char* containing "РЎРґРµР»РєР°"

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri I just need std::string containing "Сделка" instead of "РЎРґРµР»РєР°"

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri if it's impossible how does std::string str = "Абв" makes str contain "Абв" and not "РђР±РІ"

Comment: @Kekers_Dev In fact, your `std::string` contains exactly what the given `char*` contains. The difference you see is only the output showed in the console because the console cannot display non-ascii characters (by default at least). You can compare the `std::string` size and contents with those of the `char*` if you want to be sure. You'll see that they will be the same.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri thanks, there was some misunderstanding on my side. I posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out I have to convert UTF8 string into ANSI string and use the right codepage (Windows1251 in that case) to achieve the goal. It can be done with the following code I found in the internet

```cpp
string UTF8ToANSI(string s)
{
    BSTR    bstrWide;
    char*   pszAnsi;
    int     nLength;
    const char *pszCode = s.c_str();

    nLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pszCode, strlen(pszCode) + 1, NULL, NULL);
    bstrWide = SysAllocStringLen(NULL, nLength);

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pszCode, strlen(pszCode) + 1, bstrWide, nLength);

    nLength = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, bstrWide, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    pszAnsi = new char[nLength];

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, bstrWide, -1, pszAnsi, nLength, NULL, NULL);
    SysFreeString(bstrWide);

    string r(pszAnsi);
    delete[] pszAnsi;
    return r;
}
```

This problem is kind of stupid but I think it may be useful for someone. Also thanks to @Ville-Valtteri for help

EDIT:
You may need to convert ANSI Win1251 strings back to UTF8 strings. This can be done with the following code I also found in the internet:

```cpp
std::string ANSIToUTF8(std::string str)
{
    std::string res;
    int result_u, result_c;
    result_u = MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);
    if (!result_u) { return 0; }
    wchar_t *ures = new wchar_t[result_u];
    if (!MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str.c_str(), -1, ures, result_u)) {
        delete[] ures;
        return 0;
    }
    result_c = WideCharToMultiByte(65001, 0, ures, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!result_c) {
        delete[] ures;
        return 0;
    }
    char *cres = new char[result_c];
    if (!WideCharToMultiByte(65001, 0, ures, -1, cres, result_c, 0, 0)) {
        delete[] cres;
        return 0;
    }
    delete[] ures;
    res.append(cres);
    delete[] cres;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**If the string is utf8**, you *need* to e.g. set locale to utf8:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
std::cout << "Test: " << utf8str << std::endl;
```

Comment: Good luck making this work on Windows.